# Logic of adding double values

Tags: c#, java

I was given the following question in an interview...

```
Compute the following sum:
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/1048576
```

I was told that this was a logic question and they weren't looking for the source code, however my answer was the following...

```
    private static double computeSum(){
        double x = 0.0;
        for(double i=2; i<=1048576; i*=2){
            x += (1 / i);
        }
        return x;         
    }
```

What is the correct *logical* answer to this question?

Comment: I have the feeling that with the way doubles are implemented, you'll end up with exactly 1.  Power series convergence coupled with limited precision.  I've also added the interview-questions tag to your question.

Comment: yea, the answer is something like 0.99999

Comment: It's a convergent serie, it's sum is something like a0*(1/q), where a0 is a first elem of the sequence, q = a0/a1. Don't remember actually, it's from high school program :) if such a serie (with q=1/2) is infinite, the sum of it is exactly 1.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series: (1-0.5^21)/0.5 - 1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fi was presented with that sum I would say the answer is `1 minus the nth term`, so in your case it's

`1 - 1/1048576 = 1048575/1048576`

I wouldn't do any maths or code or anything. I guess that's the kind of answer they were looking for.

I might show some "working" by saying `1/2 + 1/4 = 3/4 = 1 - 1/4;` // Edit here

```
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 = 7/8 = 1 - 1/8
```

Answer (score 3):

The sum:

```
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/1048576
```

is equivalent to:

```
(1 + 2 + ... 2 ^ 20) / (2 ^ 20) - 1 =
(2 ^ 21 - 1) / (2 ^ 20) - 1 =
2 - 1 / (2 ^ 20) - 1 =
1 - 1 / (2 ^ 20) ~= 0.99999
```

The sum will tend to one if the length of the series is increased.

Answer (score 0):

They are adding fractions together until they come up with a fraction 1/1048576 which has a very negligible value. This means that the answer to the above will be very close to 1 but not exactly one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `convergent geometric series`

```
  s=a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+... to infinity
```

So the sum is

```
s=1/(1-r) where in this case r =1/2
```

However, we are seeking s-a, since the given series starts at 1/2 and not at 1. hence

```
s-a = 1/(1-r) - a = 1/(1-1/2) -1 = 1.
```

Why they call it a `logic` problem is not clear to me, except that they may want an explanation why the given geometric series converges -- which is a simple proof: i.e. the ratio between any two consecutive terms is a constant less than 1.